# How to specify external volume\folder to store inner Docker's file system (including system files and folders)

Tags: docker

Assuming I have a docker container with ubuntu inside, I want to store entire docker container's file system in some external drive (I use ubuntu as well) and share this drive with someone else, so the person will get a 'copy' of the inner state of my docker container.
Is this possible?

Comment: The normal Docker workflow would be to write a Dockerfile to build an image containing your application, check that into source control, and `docker push` the image to a registry of some sort; then your colleague could `docker pull` the image from the registry and `docker run` it.  Would that meed your needs?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to look at a proper build process with `docker build` and `docker push`. This is the "intended" way to use container images.

Anyway, there are other options for the images (basically templates where containers are build from) and the resulting containers.

I hope the below explanation helps. In case you need more details, I would appreciate a comment.

### docker save/load

With `docker save > image.tar` you will save the used image to a tarball, which can be imported via `docker load < image.tar`. This will also work on different machines.

You can look up the imported image afterward via `docker image ls`.

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/

### docker export/import

In case you want to export the complete runtime (everything after `docker run ...`) you can use `docker export > container.tar`. For the export, you need to provide the container ID, which can be fetched via `docker container ls`.

Importing works exactly the same way `docker import < container.tar`. But, you will not import a ready-to-use container. Instead, you will import an image, which can be started afterward via `docker run ...`.

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/

Comment: Is there a way to 'mount' entire docker container filesystem to some volume on external drive and reuse this volume on another PC quickly, without import\export?

Comment: I am not aware of any. It might also break a lot of stuff, since the permission handling in the container is different to a typical NTFS USB Stick.